# Redirect Url Issue with Laravel and htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

**I create virtual host for my project in local xampp. Url:  http://kooltech-us.com/**

I have folder's  name admin (From picture below ) in public folder (Laravel) .

[image]

in my project my admin login url  `http://localhost/admin/login` .

I hit url `http://localhost/admin/login` to go to admin login page .. it's okay..
but  when i hit this `http://localhost/admin` . it takes me to the public/admin folder . That means show me public Directory listing.

[image]

For prevent access Directory listing or public/admin I write in `Options - Indexes` code in .htaccess file .it's give me 403 Error ( Access forbidden! ) in general. it's work.

[image]

**I looking for  that when I hit the url `http://localhost/admin` it will take me to  `http://localhost/admin/login` .**

**Note:**

1. I did not change folder structure. (Laravel Default Folder Structure Exist).
2. Only one line code I write in .htacees file :  `Options - Indexes` . that give me 403 Error ( Access forbidden! ) in general.
3. Version "laravel/framework": "5.8.*"

I write in web.php but it's not working ..

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
  return redirect('/admin/login');
});
```

if need more explanation please comment..

Comment: did you make any changes on `.htaccess` ?

Comment: @sta i say about it .. i write Options - Indexes

Comment: @sta can you figure it out ?  have any question ? .. please ..

Comment: Default routing setup is to ignore any request that matches an existing file or folder below the public resources folder, so this request does not make it _into_ Laravel here in the first place. You will need to modify the URL rewriting in the main .htaccess accordingly, so that this request gets handed over to Laravel _despite_ matching a physically existing folder.

Comment: @CBroe would you help me..... that means what actually i will write in .htaccees file..  maybe it's  something like this (Redirect  `/old_dir/ http://www.yourdomain.com/new_dir/index.html`). i need exact solution..

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
does that

Comment: remove admin folder from public

Comment: @flakerimi  no. does not  that...

Comment: @flakerimi why i will  remove admin folder from public ? .. I need solution ..

Comment: What is in the admin folder? what are you trying to get to? It would be better if you pointed to an AdminController@index method which would deal with the request. As CBroe said above the routing is ignoring the request because of your file structure which is why @flakerimi suggested moving your admin directory.

Comment: @chris i tried  what you said ... maybe be something you skip from my question ...  I think i need  to write some code in .htacess file ...

Comment: What is in your admin directory? Do you still require normal authentication or is it just for admins? We need to see more of your code and have a better understanding of what you are trying to achieve. Yes you can achieve this by editing your .htaccess but depending on your requirements there is other ways of doing this.

Comment: @Chris will i give github repo ?

Comment: Please share more details, such that others can reproduce your problem

Comment: @NicoHaase I update my question... please review it

Comment: Just to ask this again: why is there an admin folder within the public folder? How is that supposed to work? And what have you tried for that? What about the recommendations by Chris and CBroe?

Comment: @NicoHaase i say it on my question.  I did not change folder structure. (Laravel  Default Folder Structure Exist). CBroe  comment  on my question  .. please read his comment .. I think it will help  you to understand  how is it supposed to work..

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor you must have changed the folder structure as laravel does not ship with an admin directory within it's public directory. For us to be able to help you must listen and answer the questions that are being asked.

Comment: For security reasons it's highly recommended to put the `.htaccess` at least one level up out of the public `DocumentRoot`. Just one accidentially server misconfiguration can lead to a leak of your `.htaccess` settings and further leaks based on that informations while it's served to the client in plain text.

Comment: @codekandis you are absolutely  right ..  my one local client give me this project to fix some issue. this project will not be hosted online . it's small inventory system. he will use it  in PC. that is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify the .htaccess you would need to add something like this to your .htaccess This will redirect all request from /admin to /public but still show as /admin which will allow your redirect in `web.php` to work:-

```
RewriteRule admin /public [L]
```

Which would give you:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule admin /public [L] 
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    
</IfModule>
```

However I still feel that this is bad practice, and changing your directory strcture as @flakerimi sugested would be a much better solution.

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer instead of linking to external ressources

Comment: @Nico, there is a lot to explain here.. why duplicate what is already written on the posted website? Am I not allowed to refer to external sites?

Comment: No, linking to external pages is not allowed. They might change or be removed completely, which would make your answer worthless

Comment: @Chris please review my question .. if something is not clear .. please comment...

Comment: @Chris  did you try it ?

Comment: Yes, I tried ot on a fresh install of laravel, I do not know your exact endpoint which is why I said someething like this, but you say admin/login works and the above redirects to admin/login

Comment: @Chris please explain how this line `RewriteRule admin admin/login [L,R] ` work in .htaccess file. where you write `Options - Indexes` code  ?   it's not working  .

Comment: I have no idea where you have put `Options - Indexes` the .htaccess example I have given should go inside your public directory, I do not see any changes to your question. Have you tried doing this using the single front controller method? I had a look through your github page and think that if you expand your [roles-permissions](https://github.com/abdullahalnoor/roles-permissions) repository it will give you what you require.

Comment: @Chris I write after this line `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor I do not understand what you have done and you continue to refuse to answer my questions, I believe you are trying to waste my time and are not actually trying any of the answers/suggestions. Many users have tried to help you but you are not helping yourself. Have a good day.

Comment: @Chris this is not what actually you are thinking .. I am actually looking for the ans... Have a good day also...btw thanks

Comment: join me in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219951/room-for-chris-and-abdullah-al-noor

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor after our conversation I have a better understanding of your project, please see my edited answer

Comment: This did not work for me my admin is not on the public folder but on the root directory. So I also need a better rewrite for my own case. please any help